# jquery: detach() not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I've written some code that utilizes append() and detach() to hide and reveal full screen navigation.

In Safari, detach(), to hide the navigation, is not working. Any help as to why is greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var nav = $('#nav');
  var menu = $('#menu');
  var navLabel = $('#nav span')
  var menuItems = $('#menu li');

  menu.detach();
  navLabel.attr('data-content','Menu');

    nav.click(function(){

        console.log(menu.css("opacity"));

        if (menuOpacity == 0){

            $("body").append(menu).after(nav);
            menuOpacity = 1;
            menu.css("opacity");
            menu.css("opacity","0.99");
      navLabel.attr('data-content','Back');

            } else if ( menuOpacity == 1 && menu.css("opacity") == 0.99 ) {

                menuOpacity = 0;
                menu.css("opacity");
                menu.css("opacity","0");
                menu.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
                    menu.detach();
                    $(this).off();
                });
        navLabel.attr('data-content','Menu');
            }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What's not working specifically?

Comment: Hi, @EricGuan! Thank you for taking a look at my problem! When I click/press the button to remove/detach the menu, nothing happens. The menu stays in the open state.